# Why long data type support underscore (_) in jdk 7?

Tags: java, java-7, long-integer, numeric

I have seen the new feature of the JDK 7.

There is the long data type support the Underscore ("_") ?
What is other use of the feature.?

for ex.

> long l = 123_456_789L;

Comment: Every numeric type supports it in Java 7 (or newer). What exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is why? what is the use of this feature?

Comment: It makes numbers easier to read? Or do you consider `953184531324L` easier to read than `953_184_531_324L`?

Answer (score 0):

not only longs as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html)

```
long creditCardNumber = 1234_5678_9012_3456L;
long socialSecurityNumber = 999_99_9999L;
float pi =  3.14_15F;
long hexBytes = 0xFF_EC_DE_5E;
long hexWords = 0xCAFE_BABE;
long maxLong = 0x7fff_ffff_ffff_ffffL;
byte nybbles = 0b0010_0101;
long bytes = 0b11010010_01101001_10010100_10010010;
```

you can even do

```
int x = 5_______2;
```

but why?  oracle wants to improve the readability of the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's just for the sake of readability. As [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) says:

> This feature enables you, for example, to separate groups of digits in numeric literals, which can improve the readability of your code.
>
> For instance, if your code contains numbers with many digits, you can use an underscore character to separate digits in groups of three, similar to how you would use a punctuation mark like a comma, or a space, as a separator.

The following example shows other ways you can use the underscore in numeric literals:

```
long creditCardNumber = 1234_5678_9012_3456L;
long socialSecurityNumber = 999_99_9999L;
float pi =  3.14_15F;
long hexBytes = 0xFF_EC_DE_5E;
long hexWords = 0xCAFE_BABE;
long maxLong = 0x7fff_ffff_ffff_ffffL;
byte nybbles = 0b0010_0101;
long bytes = 0b11010010_01101001_10010100_10010010;
```